# Link with underscore does not work

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, hyperlinks

Underscore in URL gets escaped to %5F and does not work.

I'm trying to use an underscore in a link in [my answers at stackoverlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1305004/in-sqlite3-will-this-select-statement-benefit-from-two-indexes/1309028#1309028). However, the link does not work in the resulting HTML.

This is similar to the discussion [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3657/can-an-unescaped-underscore-be-included-in-a-link). But the answers doesn't work for me. Specifically, I use the provided editor to create the link which should work according this answer.

Is there a way to avoid the escaping?

The link works in Internet Explorer but not in Firefox. So it might be a Firefox bug. But strangely the link works with Firefox from the editors preview!?

Comment: It seems that nowadays the underscore is no longer escaped to be `%5F`. That is good, as Firefox treats an escaped underscore differently than Chrome, which might mess up when the server is not configured correctly. Like try `http://pear.php.net/package/XML%5FSerializer` in both browsers. In Firefox note the URL in the 404 message (and the encoded `GET` [in its request](http://i.stack.imgur.com/P7P7S.png)), while the URL loads just fine in Chrome.

Answer (score 2):

What should I tell the kind folks at sqlite.org to fix their webserver to deal with this issue?

When I link to [this page](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_update.html) (http://www.sqlite.org/lang%5Fupdate.html) I get the following:

> Document Not Found
>
> The document
>   /lang_5Fupdate.html is not avaivable
>   on this server

I would call this a fringe issue, except that sqlite.org is a reputable, well-known site.

Comment: Apparently, somewhere in the past 2 years, they *did* change (or: *fix*?) the server configuration. (The current Firefox still asks for `document/lang_%5Fupdate.html`, but today that is handled fine by that server. Chrome asks for the URL with a real underscore even when using the encoded URL, and hence has no issues no matter how the server is configured.)

Answer (score 2):

A fix for this would be good - I want to link to some github repositories from careers. However, the URLs have underscores, and github.com doesn't handle this issue either, so I have no way of linking to that work from my careers page.

Anyone clicking on the link ends up with a 404 page - not cool. I want to show off my awesomeness, but markdown is mocking me!

I realize that it's technically legal to escape underscores, but it's not mandatory.

From http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt

```
2.3. Unreserved Characters

   Data characters that are allowed in a URI but do not have a reserved
   purpose are called unreserved.  These include upper and lower case
   letters, decimal digits, and a limited set of punctuation marks and
   symbols.

      unreserved  = alphanum | mark

      mark        = "-" | "_" | "." | "!" | "~" | "*" | "'" | "(" | ")"

   Unreserved characters can be escaped without changing the semantics
   of the URI, but this should not be done unless the URI is being used
   in a context that does not allow the unescaped character to appear.
```

Comment: And [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#Percent-encoding_unreserved_characters), emphasis mine: URIs that differ only by whether an unreserved character is percent-encoded or appears literally are equivalent by definition, but URI processors, in practice, may not always recognize this equivalence. For example, URI consumers *shouldn't* treat "`%41`" differently from "`A`" or "`%7E`" differently from "`~`", but some do. **For maximum interoperability, URI producers are discouraged from percent-encoding unreserved characters.**

Answer (score 1):

Bottom line, the destination webserver is configured incorrectly, because %5F and _ are equivalent.

We had a lot of issues with underscores in URLs causing markdown problems (among other unusual characters), so we auto-escape them.

Comment: I've the destination server is the problem, why does it work from IE 8 and in the preview?

Comment: Maybe you can resolve those markdown problems differently. Try: http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?type=visualization#column%5Fchart vs http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?type=visualization#column_chart

Comment: Correct, the target webserver should handle this, but we don't always have control over it.

Comment: Automatically change all URLs to bit.ly URLs and you wouldn't have this problem

Answer (score 1):

I have the exact same issue on SO. Unfortunately we do not always have the power to reconfigure the destination webserver. I work around it by manually putting anchor hrefs in the editor, but I occasionally forget and end up with a broken link. Then I have to go back and edit my answer to fix the link.

Please consider coming up with a resolution for this issue.