# URL encoding bug

Tags: support, url-encoding

From [Is there some way to convert json to xml in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/856833/is-there-some-way-to-convert-json-to-xml-in-php)

The link [XML Serializer](http://pear.php.net/package/XML_Serializer) link encodes the `_`, which causes a failure on the destination site:

```
The requested document /package/XML%5FSerializer was not found on this server.
```

The link works fine here on Meta, but not within the question on SO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The HTML indeed was `<a href="http://pear.php.net/package/XML%5FSerializer" ...>` for that. It's an old post and the HTML is "cooked" (cached) [when a post is saved](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48596/when-does-the-question-answer-text-get-converted-from-markdown-to-html/48598#48598). Making a dummy edit has meanwhile fixed that HTML, just like more recent posts (like your question above) use the underscore in the HTML source.

But, that "fix" aside: I think your browser should really support it. My Chrome on a Mac has no problems following that link. However, Firefox on my Mac [does fail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P7P7S.png), as it apparently sends a different URL to the web server. Chrome versus Firefox:

```
GET /package/XML_Serializer HTTP/1.1
Host: pear.php.net
```

```
GET /package/XML%5FSerializer HTTP/1.1
Host: pear.php.net
```

[Wikipedia states](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#Types_of_URI_characters) states that the underscore is an unreserved character and does not *need* percent encoding (emphasis mine):

> Characters from the unreserved set never need to be percent-encoded.
>
> URIs that differ only by whether an unreserved character is percent-encoded or appears literally are equivalent by definition, but URI processors, in practice, may not always recognize this equivalence. For example, URI consumers *shouldn't* treat "`%41`" differently from "`A`" or "`%7E`" differently from "`~`", but some do. **For maximum interoperability, URI producers are discouraged from percent-encoding unreserved characters.**

I guess that's why eventually the encoding changed, though [for long](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16004/link-with-underscore-does-not-work/16019#16019) SE did use `%5F` on purpose.

Answer (score 1):

> The link works fine here on Meta, but not within the question on SO.

This means it was fixed already, but old posts aren't updated until they're edited. Make a tiny edit to re-cook the HTML and it should work.