# In comments, `_foo_` in links breaks the HTML link target href

Tags: bug, hyperlinks, broken-link

I tried to link in a comment to this image:

```
https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/85/Concorde_Cockpit_-_geograph.org.uk_-_1357498.jpg
```

However, it gets cut off semingly at a pair of underscores surrounded by a similar pair of non-alphanumeric characters:

```
https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/85/Concorde_Cockpit_-
```

and is displayed with the remainder in italics, except for the surrounding underscores:

```
<a href="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/85/Concorde_Cockpit_-" rel="nofollow">upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/85/Concorde_Cockpit_-</a><i>geograph.‌​org.uk</i>-_1357498.jpg
```

[This answer by Jeff Atwood](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/16019/157730) from back in 2009 is on the only question I can find easily that isn't closed as a duplicate, but it says that underscores are escaped. This isn't (URI entity) escaping, it's rewriting, and it's breaking perfectly legitimate links, for example in the comments to [this answer on Aviation SE](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/2884/753).

Comment: Note that manually escaping the underscores (i.e. `https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/85/Concorde_Cockpit_-\_geograph.org.uk\_-_1357498.jpg`) fixes the link.

Comment: @AnnaLear That might very well qualify as a workaround, but certainly not as a fix; and if I, who have been pretty much of a regular on Stack Exchange for the last three and a half years at least, didn't think to try that, then relative newcomers certainly can't be expected to know about such a trick. I still feel this issue needs some sort of proper fix.