# Converting returns to newlines or not

Tags: discussion, markdown, linebreak

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should the markdown renderer treat a single line break as <br>?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26011/should-the-markdown-renderer-treat-a-single-line-break-as-br)

Quoth http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001317.html

> Item #3, the conversion of returns to linebreaks, is somewhat more debatable. I'm on the fence on that one, but I do believe it's significant enough to warrant an explicit choice either way.

Who
really
prefers
that
hitting
Enter
(without
two
spaces
on
the
end
of
the
line)
be
treated
like
a
space
instead
of
a
line-break?
Jeff
appears
to
be
under
the
impression
that
Enter-as-space
is
preferable
in
some
circumstances.
I'd
please
love
to
know
what
those
cases
are.

Thanks,
billpg.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect the actual reason for this behavior, this feature, comes
from Markdown's reliance on USENET and plain-text email traditions
for its formatting hints. On these systems, [breaking each line at 70
characters](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/5378effc-092c-4547-b357-d18c661423a0/view-source) was commonly used to ensure such text would be readable
on older systems; clients would then reformat the text for display on
the client system, ignoring single, intra-paragraph line-breaks and
using an empty line as a cue that the author intended the previous
paragraph to end.

While no longer *strictly* necessary, this is still not that uncommon
among users composing text in editors that do not automatically wrap
text, including many fine "programmer's editors".

Personally, I have no strong feelings either way; I've used systems
that **do** insert a hard break for every line-break, and still found
them annoying in some instances (primarily those where I wanted
double line breaks while composing the text in places where this
resulted in too much vertical whitespace in the final text). I
think the users who suffer the most are those who never bothered to
read instructions anyway *and* are unfamiliar with either the old
text-only traditions or modern HTML.

Answer (score 1):

I favour `<p>` over `<br>`, but still would like *some* way to get `<br>` if, and only if, *really* needed. The current Markdown works fine for me.

As a user/visitor of whatever site I think it's good to adhere to the layout that is (currently) defined by its owners, like the CSS whitespace formatting many sites have defined for paragraphs. I feel one should not try to use `<br>` to change that. Doing so might also break any future layout changes.

I like the blank line while editing, as that makes it much clearer that I really started a new paragraph, especially when the last line of the previous paragraph extends all the way to the end of that last line.

I also [like](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/10/markdown-one-year-later/) the explicit two-spaces for `<br>`, as that makes it just a bit more difficult to get such `<br>`.

If anything is changed, then I'd still like `<br>` to be an exception. For example: I would not mind if both a single and multiple Returns are converted into a single `<p>`. (I would still be pressing Return twice then, while others might happily use only one. I am not sure if that affects usage of the data dump in any way? Or other usage like screen readers or the API?) But I'd *not* like each Return to become a `<br>`.

(And am I wrong to think that whoever doesn't look at the preview, or does not click "edit"  after seeing the result, does not *really* care about any formatting anyway...?)

Comment: I tend to think that not looking at the preview is a sign of being a reasonable human.

Comment: Actually, @billpg, you might be right. I'm far too focussed on the end-result. Like I often reformat code, or even switch to using a quote rather than a pre-formatted block, if a pre-formatted block gives me horizontal scrollbars... I need help! ;-)