# Numbering/bullet interpretation bug?

Tags: bug, status-completed, markdown, list

364. The number to the left shows up as a "1." even though I typed in "364."  Very annoying.

Comment: As requested in http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46138/is-it-possible-to-override-the-default-numbering-of-lists-in-markdown, the start number should be overridable (as it is in normal <li> tags).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

...but by design.

From [Markdown Editing Help](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help):

```
A numbered <ol> list:

1. Numbered lists are easy
2. Markdown keeps track of the numbers for you
7. So this will be item 3.
```

As a workaround type a backslash before the dot:

```
364\. This won't become a list. (But hence it won't indent nicely either. 
      No matter if you try to indent yourself. It won't indent nicely.)
```

364. This won't become a list. (But hence it won't indent nicely either. 
      No matter if you try to indent yourself. It won't indent nicely.)

Comment: I take advantage of this feature all the time if you check the markdown source of any of my posts that contain ordered lists.

Comment: That's truly an advantage indeed ;-) http://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/34480/list

Comment: Yuck, so I have to go out of my way to prevent it mangling what I typed, rather than being able to specify when I do want it to mangle my input.  :-(

Comment: For most the quest is about getting newlines ;-)  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26011/should-the-markdown-renderer-treat-a-single-line-break-as-br (But then, I guess it's much more of a quest for those on non-technical stackexchange.com sites, not so much on our SO/SF/SU?)

Comment: Nice thing is that you don't even need to type the numbers. You can just use 1. for the first, and then - for the next ones. I like that feature :) Restarting lists on a different number would be nice though... but I don't think this is too easy in html either? Or perhaps there is some newer CSS thing to do that as well... probably is...

Comment: Yup, the *"Markdown keeps track of the numbers for you"* really is *"your browser will start at 1 and increment for each item"*... HTML *did* allow for `<ol start="42">`, but that has been deprecated, I guess in favour of CSS `counter-reset: item 41;` and `li:before` styles referring to such counter -- http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_gen_counter-reset.asp

Comment: Meanwhile, [`start` is no longer deprecated](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/ol.html#ol.attrs.start). And restarting numbering is [now supported on SE as well](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137077/cant-start-a-numbered-list-on-a-number-other-than-1/239121#239121), @Svish.

Answer (score 6):

The other alternative is to do lists in a format Markdown doesn't understand

1) Like

2) This

3) List

But as previously noted, you won't get proper list indentation. This actually has some advantages when it comes to code blocks being mixed in with lists..

Comment: Good info to have.  I'll keep that workaround in mind.

Comment: It seems this (particular method) has changed.

Answer (score 2):

You can now start lists with numbers other than 1.; see [Can't start a numbered list on a number other than 1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137077/cant-start-a-numbered-list-on-a-number-other-than-1).