# Add parenthesis as an accepted Markdown ordered list delimiter

Tags: feature-request, markdown, list

The Markdown editor knows that an empty line, followed by a number, followed by a period, followed by a space, is a list item.

1. This works great
2. It's almost magic

The problem is that I almost always use a close parenthesis for my lists. I think it's a pretty common practice, but the problem is that the editor / Markdown parser doesn't accept parenthesis as an acceptable list delimiter:

1. This fails horribly
2. This is on the next line I swear

Comment: Parens are used for letters {a) b) c)} not for numbers [1. 2. 3.].

Comment: @random / @John: it depends where you're are from. In many countries 1), 2) is what is usually used.

Comment: @Koper, then only if those countries use English one *could* consider using it here as well?

Comment: I'm glad this wasn't implemented, and hope it never will be. Currently it's my favorite way to get around uncooperative automatic numbered list formatting.

Comment: @LadybugKiller Tell this to the millions of new users using parens for their enumerations for whatever cultural reasons.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's transformed into HTML, and rendered by your browser. So even if 1)... 2)... were recognized, the output would still be

```
<ol>
<li>First item</li>
<li>Second item</li>
</ol>
```

...and the output would still be

1. First item
2. Second item

So the change would allow markup that other Markdown engines wouldn't recognize, and produce exactly the same output. You might as well just get used to the period.

Answer (score 13):

It is not a bad idea, but too significant a deviation from the Markdown specification to be viable, IMO.

Comment: I was afraid a little change might take a lot of work.

Answer (score 9):

People [might](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35181/numbering-bullet-interpretation-bug/35206#35206) currently be using this to *avoid* an automatic list. So, no, please.

1) one
3) two
6) three

Comment: Exactly what I came here to post when I saw this post pop up in my search results.

Answer (score 7):

I have never seen anyone use parentheses to avoid a numbered list. It's always been the case that the author intends to create a numbered list of some kind.

Now, if HTML and CSS are incapable of producing a list with parentheses, then by all means use dots. But I'm getting a little tired of editing questions that use parentheses.

Answer (score 7):

Parenthesis-delimited lists using `1)` now work on Meta Stack Exchange:

1. [We're switching to CommonMark](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/348746/were-switching-to-commonmark)

Answer (score 5):

This is indeed an extremely useful feature. In fact it is not so much a question of convenience but much more about all the new users (likely unaware of proper markdown rules) that use parens for their enumerations, probably due to different cultural standards.

One of the biggest advantages of markdown is that it is so intuitive and that text written properly structured in its raw form usually works right out of the box when processed by markdown. It really happens very often that posts from new users with enumeration lists require an edit to be properly formatted simply because they used parens instead of dots. Implementing this alternative markdown syntax would thus highly reduce the necessity to reformat every feeled 2nd enumeration list.

Also note, that the recently developed [CommonMark](http://commonmark.org/) standard seems to support paren-style enumeration, too. But while there are [existing requests](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/238957/162011) for implementing this here, the possiblity and time frame of this implementation are still rather vague and implementing this extended enumeration style should be easier and faster than that (like the recently introduced possibility to start lists at numbers other than 1).

Comment: Yep, so numbered lists in common can be delimited with periods or close parens ([see the spec here](http://jgm.github.io/stmd/spec.html#lists)), so if/when they get around to implementing the One True Spec this question becomes [meta-tag:status-completed]

Comment: @Won't Still I'd rather like to see this implemented before the *possible* CommonMark implementation in 2 years.

Comment: Turns out it was 5.5 rather than 2 years. But at least it might be solved soon. ;-)

Answer (score 5):

CommonMark allows for

1) parenthesis
2) delimited
3) ordered
4) lists

---

https://commonmark.org/help/

[Will CommonMark be adopted for SE?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238957/will-commonmark-be-adopted-for-se)

---

[image: CommonMark rules]

Comment: (I write after having edited yet another parenthesis-formatted ordered list.)

Answer (score -2):

If you want to get an ordered list with parenthesis, you have to add a non-breaking space before each letter. In Mac, for example, you get a non-breaking space with option+space –it will appear a dot (.) in a red background.

So:

option+space a)

option+space b)

and so on..

As I said this works for Mac. For other languages see:
[How do I ensure that whitespace is preserved in Markdown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15721373/how-do-i-ensure-that-whitespace-is-preserved-in-markdown)

Hope it helps!

Comment: That is not the purpose of the question, please read it again.

Comment: The question says: "but the problem is that the editor / Markdown parser doesn't accept parenthesis as an acceptable list delimiter". And I'm just offering a way to get it done..

Comment: No. The meaning is that the question author wants to write `1)` and that would get rendered as a list, same as `1.` and that is indeed the current behavior after SE switched to CommonMark.

Comment: That's precisely what my code does.. :) If you write, in Mac, option+space 1), R will not treat it as an ordered list and it will show 1) instead of 1.