# Allow "1)"-format for numbered lists

Tags: feature-request, markdown, list

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Add parenthesis to period as an accepted list delimiter](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39684/add-parenthesis-to-period-as-an-accepted-list-delimiter)

When editing other people's posts to correct some formatting issues, I've often run into people assuming that the following format would work for numbered lists:

```
1) Item 1
2) Item 2
3) Item 3
```

The result, however, is less than pleasing:

1) Item 1
2) Item 2
3) Item 3

It seems like a pretty common way of formatting lists in plaintext, so I'd like to ask if it'd be possible to extend the markdown syntax to allow for this?

Comment: If people don't know how to format, that's their issue. Markdown is Markdown and I don't think there's a benefit from *extending* its syntax. It only causes confusion because you lose consistency.

Comment: +1.  Can you believe @Random closed my original as "too localized?"  Abuse of mod powers!

Comment: At the time "Not constructive" wasn't an option. @won

Comment: @random: Not constructive? *Not constructive??* ***NOT CONSTRUCTIVE???*** I'll have you note that JA said it was "not a bad idea."  So there nyah.

Comment: Why do people not look at the preview when they are asking a question?  Don't they realize their markdown syntax is wrong?  Do they even look at the question after it's posted?

Comment: @Rocket: What the <b>hell</b> is Markdown? ;)

Comment: @BoltClock: <marquee><blink>HTML FTW</blink></marquee>

Answer (score 1):

Use two spaces at the end of each line to force a newline [note that ' ' has been replaced with '_' to view whitespace]:

```
1)_Item_1__
2)_Item_2__
3)_Item_3__
```

produces:

1) Item 1
2) Item 2
3) Item 3

Comment: This isn't the same as actually producing a numbered list

Comment: True @Michael, but it does give a rendering that renders like a list should. I read the question as asking for the text to look like a list, not that Markdown had to know it was such.

Comment: The question was intended for the Markdown parser to recognize that format in the same way it recognizes "1. ..." lists, to allow for things to Just Work™ for new users. Having to know that you need two spaces at the end of each line defeats the point in that. :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that the point of the syntax is that it be intuitive—"this should work because it is natural that it do so"—but rather that it is simple and well-defined. The syntax that exists now for numbered lists works well. If the only reason for changing it is that it's a "common way" to format them, then that's not a good enough reason. The syntax now has already been engrained in current users' minds, and introducing a second acceptable syntax for the same result is just superfluous and could even lead to confusion. Besides, a uniform way of displaying them (with the `.` instead of the `)`) is just prettier.

Furthermore, SE has [already been working hard to make it easier for new users to understand Markdown](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/04/inline-comment-and-post-markdown-help/). A "preview" section has long existed that shows users exactly how their posts will appear. And, for newbies who have no idea how to format it by hand, there are WYSIWYG editor controls right above the text box. How could it be any easier?

Unfortunately, even if the site were to adopt a new syntax, it wouldn't solve the problem, since you can chalk almost all formatting errors up to laziness.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from having to change those to a space and a period, what benefit is gained?

We should let people get away with stuff when the rules are broadly posted?

Can we do that at the golf course? Can I just knock a divot out and then walk away from it? Can I do that on the green too?

I understand your frustration, but either they care (like you do) or they don't.

## I vote no

---

I had to experiment

### periods

1. this is a list
2. this is a list
3. this is a list

   1. this is a list
   2. this is a list
   3. this is a list

### and now parens

1) this is a list
2) this is a list
3) this is a list

1) this is a list
 2) this is a list
 3) this is a list

```
I had to experiment

##periods

1. this is a list
2. this is a list
3. this is a list

 1. this is a list
 2. this is a list
 3. this is a list

##and now parens

1) this is a list
2) this is a list
3) this is a list

 1) this is a list
 2) this is a list
 3) this is a list
```

Comment: Er...really? The benefit is a common list format works and life gets a little easier for editors

Comment: @Michael Yes, but only here. The point of using Markdown is using it in the way it was *meant to be used* and not stacking things on top of it only to make life easier for people who don't care about properly formatting.

Comment: Also see [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39684/add-parenthesis-to-period-as-an-accepted-list-delimiter/39777#39777).