# Allow alternate list formatting

Tags: feature-request, markdown-rendering

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Add parenthesis to period as an accepted list delimiter](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39684/add-parenthesis-to-period-as-an-accepted-list-delimiter)

On Stack Exchange sites, I can write an ordered list as such:

1. Item One
2. Item Two
3. Item Three

… and expect it to turn into the proper HTML markup. However, I often see people writing lists like this :

1) Item One

2) Item Two

3) Item Three

… which renders as plain text, not as a correct ordered list. Would it be possible to have support for *both* ways of writing ordered lists?