# Markdown for ordered lists, starting with zero?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, markdown, design

I see that you can create an ordered list using Markdown notation like the following.

```
1. line 1
2. line 2
3. line 3
...
N. line N
```

The Markdown content supports starting each line with any arbitrary number and reorders the list starting with 1. I'd like to start an ordered list with zero. My use case for zero would be in describing capture groups from regular expressions where group zero always returns the entire string. So I'd like to display something like this:

```
# Groups
0. Entire string
1. The first capture group you were looking for
2. The second capture group
3. The third group with the string I heart Kittens
```

Markdown instead reorders the group and forces the ordered list to start at 1:

[image: Picture of renumbered list]

Trying to force the issue with inline HTML: `<ol start="0">` or `<ol><li value="0">entire string</li></ol>` doesn't work either. Any ideas on how I can create ordered list starting with zero?

If it's not possible to do so, then this is a feature-request.

Comment: You make your feature requests right here on meta.

Comment: By tagging the question as a "feature-request" ?

Comment: Yes that should be sufficient for the correct people to notice the request.

Comment: You could use parentheses and newlines as a workaround

Comment: I'm neither for this nor against this request, however I'm pretty sure it's not possible with the current markdown and I believe [this answer by Jeff](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/39777/152859) holds true here as well: *Not a bad idea, but too significant a deviation from the markdown spec to be viable*.

Comment: I'm not sure how technically possible this is. I mean, I think there is some CSS to change the beginning of a list, not sure what about browser support though.

Comment: The thing is, @ShaWizDowArd, that that other request which Jeff called a significant deviation from the markdown spec, would be a deviation from *markdown*, whereas this one could be done with a HTML workaround, without changing markdown itself.