# Make • a <ul>-creation character

Tags: feature-request, markdown, list

Recently-ish, over on Stack Apps, [the post for the official Android app](https://stackapps.com/q/4240/21692) was edited to actually contain information, rather than just being a placeholder. During this process, the staff member clearly copied a bulleted list in, as indicated by this Markdown source excerpt:

```
• Track all your interests in one place with the new combined feed view
• Get instant notifications when you receive an answer or comment
• Search for questions, or browse by tag
• Ask, answer, comment and vote on questions
```

In source view, this looks fine. But try to render it, and:

> • Track all your interests in one place with the new combined feed view
>   • Get instant notifications when you receive an answer or comment
>   • Search for questions, or browse by tag
>   • Ask, answer, comment and vote on questions

I edited the post to use `*` instead of `•` to start list items, and all was good. But it got me thinking about U+2022 BULLET, the unsung hero of unordered lists. I mean, it's the default list-item-start display character in just about everything, and yet it's not recognised as such in source:

```
* `*` list item
• `•` list item
+ `+` list item
- `-` list item
```

> - `*` list item
>     • `•` list item
> - `+` list item
> - `-` list item

*Really*.

**End the discrimination against U+2022!**

Comment: And in the same vein, 1) 2) 3) should create an ordered list as well.

Comment: As for 1), 2), 3), see [Add parenthesis to period as an accepted list delimiter](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39684/add-parenthesis-to-period-as-an-accepted-list-delimiter).

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid it will just add more confusion than it solves.

- Assuming *"it's the default list-item-start display character in just about everything"* is true, many other bullets will *look* like that round bullet, but would then not trigger rendering into a list. Confusion.

- Where to stop? Nested lists often use different bullets, but would be ignored. Confusion. (And what about `<strong>`, `<em>`, formatted links, ...?)

- Automatically changing the bullets into proper Markdown list identifiers (right after pasting, not while saving a post) would probably be very annoying when one actually wants that character for something else.

Given the above, I don't feel it's worth another [deviation from the Markdown specification](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74999/so-specific-markup-definitive-resource), which might break rendering of apps using [the API](http://api.stackexchange.com/) or [data dumps](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/01/stack-exchange-cc-data-now-hosted-by-the-internet-archive/).

Comment: (But then: [Implement ```-style Markdown code blocks](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125148/implement-style-markdown-code-blocks) seems to be on the roadmap, so maybe trying to keep to the Markdown spec is flogging a dead horse.)

Comment: So add more bullets to the recognised-list. Shouldn't be that hard.