# Including support for HTML tables in posts

Tags: discussion, feature-request, markdown

Currently, SE sites have a good bit of [basic HTML](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed-on-stack-exchange-sites) at the ready. We have `<p>`, `<a>`, `<h1>`,`<h2>`,`<blockquote>` and more. I think this was a really neat idea, and beneficial in areas like post clarity, organization and style. I would like to add a tag to the supported list.

I want to propose SE also support HTML tables. I often find myself asking posts that have a tabular section, ranging from numerical data, hardware choices to terminologies, ect. It's not just me either, there are lots of instances where other askers/answerers are resorting to pictures or crude text tables to achieve a tabular appearance.

In light of the limited options for tables on SE sites, adding support for table tags: `<table>`, `<tr>`,`<th>` might increase post clarity. Granted, not everyone knows HTML sytax, but that user group is growing. Also, we already have so many HTML tags; what's three more? Here is what a basic table could look like:

```
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th> 
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td> 
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td> 
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**Question:** Would SE consider it worthwhile to add support for table tabs? In terms of cost-benefit analysis, I see support for table tags as a low-cost high-benefit scenario. But am I alone in this line of reasoning? Maybe I have over-looked costs somewhere?

Also would this need to be done at a site by site basis, or could SE add blanket functionality?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ wow, that's an old post, 7 years ago! I'm surprised we haven't got further along. Is there something holding us up?

Comment: Maybe the reasons why it was declined 7 years ago didn't change yet?

Comment: Before anything will change, I'm sure they first move to [CommonMark](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238957/will-commonmark-be-adopted-for-se/258587#258587) and last time I checked tables were not covered yet in the CommonMark core spec. There is one relevant change made recently that maybe. maybe, maybe opens up the possibility to support tables in posts and that is due to the responsive redesign that got rid of the html  tables that were used to layout Questions and answers. At least that was the reason used to explain that tables in posts would be bad.