# How to get uniform markdown output for questions to be posted both on SE and Reddit?

Tags: support, bug, design, markdown

I thought it would be as simple as starting on one and then copy and pasting to the latter; between SE <> Reddit, whichever was first.

But I've found that it does not always turn out the same.

There are lot of tiny differences in layout, formatting and white space handling that happen during the course of such attempts.

How could one get around this?

Comment: Markdown isn't even standard between comments, posts and answers. Commonmark should have helped but was only really supported on docs.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek - You mean this - http://commonmark.org/ - Thanks I will look into it. I wonder why people give negative to a valid question/ concern.

Comment: Yup. It was supposed to help get a standard dialect of markdown but never really happened here :(

Comment: @JourneymanGeek - Is there a minimalist MD dialect (CM or so) that works most places? Or an Editor that helps or constraints one to such a "schema" or so?

Comment: Not as far as I know. Else I would be posting an answer, not comments

Comment: Kinda like the old Browser wars where HTML stuff was not similarly supported in them but the Basics worked everywhere so if you remained compliant with that Subset then you were safe.. any other stuff and you risked browser compliance issues

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is "you can't".

The long answer is "maybe someday you'll be able to do this, and you can help a little bit in getting to that day", but we'll get back to that later.

I don't use reddit, but from a quick look at [their Markdown guide](https://www.reddit.com/r/reddit.com/comments/6ewgt/reddit_markdown_primer_or_how_do_you_do_all_that/c03nik6/) (okay, technically, that link isn't official, but their [actual official page](https://www.reddit.com/wiki/commenting) links directly to it), it looks like a superset of [Stack-flavored Markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

The easiest workaround in practice is to not use the following things in reddit, or manually remove them when copying to Stack:

- `^` for superscripts
- `~~` for strikethroughs
- `>!secrets!<` for spoiler blocks
- any kind of table formatting (alternatively, do use it, and wrap it all in a code block when it's on Stack, even though that's semantically wrong)

The *reason* for all of this is that Markdown itself started out as an imperfect spec, [according to Jeff Atwood](https://blog.codinghorror.com/the-future-of-markdown/), one of the co-founders of Stack. As a result, different places made up their own variants with the gaps filled in in ways that were helpful for their individual use cases.

To try to deal with this, Atwood and a few others, including people from both Stack and reddit, started an initiative called [CommonMark](http://commonmark.org/)—although it wasn't always called that; there was [some unpleasantness](https://blog.codinghorror.com/standard-markdown-is-now-common-markdown/) with the guy who [created Markdown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown#History), the venerable John Gruber of [Daring Fireball](http://daringfireball.net/)—which is where you can help (see, I didn't forget what I said at the top of this answer).

CommonMark has [a "How can I help?" page](http://commonmark.org/#how) that (over)simplifies to "write some code" and "use the thing". On top of that, you can try to lobby various places on the Internet to switch their implementations to CommonMark. For CommonMark here on SE, see [Will CommonMark be adopted for SE?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238957/will-commonmark-be-adopted-for-se).

Comment: Note tht **there is** a spoiler block. [ref](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1191/add-markdown-support-for-hidden-until-you-click-text-aka-spoilers/71396#71396)

Comment: Yes there is __a__ spoiler block, but the syntax is different (`>! some stuff !<` vs. `>! other stuff`). Similarly, superscripts and strikethroughs are supported, but with different syntax.