# Is it possible to override the default numbering of lists in Markdown?

Tags: support, markdown

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Numbering/bullet interpretation bug?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35181/numbering-bullet-interpretation-bug)

Sometimes I want to have some text between my numbered list items, but when I resume my list, markdown automatically starts counting from 1 again.

1. Waffle.

honey

2. 2nd waffle.

This should be a delicious honey waffle sandwich, but markdown numbers the second waffle "1" even though I typed "2" which is really putting me off my sandwich.

1. Yes, I know
   that this
2. works.

but that's not what I want, I don't want the middle line indented because that implies it's related to the first point when semantically, I don't want it to be.

Is there a way to get my list/waffle sandwich how I like it or do I just have to live with it?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35181/numbering-bullet-interpretation-bug/35206#35206

Comment: @Random: Frick, what is it with you and duplicates. :) how do you find them so well. Thanks. Kind of a shame you lose the list indenting, you can't have everything I suppose.

Comment: Huh, seriously I need 5 votes to close my own question. @Random feel free to finish it off.

Comment: Just using the site search to find them. And spending too much time here to see the various ways to reword certain topics.