# Numbered list item 2 appears as 1 in my answer... what is causing it?

Tags: support, markdown, code-formatting, list

I have an answer on SO like this

```
1. step

Some text

2. step
```

Problem it looks like this

> 1. step
>
> Some text
>
> 2. step

Why is it making 2 appear as 1?

Link
[CSS two level menu - second level doesn't appear in proper position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17632515/css-two-level-menu-second-level-doesnt-appear-in-proper-position/17632678#17632678)

What am I doning wrong here?

Comment: Don't know why but you can get over it by erasing the space: `2.Step`.

Comment: this is not really a duplicate as im not using lists

Comment: This is part of markdown: if you put "1." followed by a space, it will become a list item. It's the same like if you put something between "**" it will become bold. If that's not your intention in that answer sorry, feel free to rollback my edit.

Comment: Then you need to say you're not using lists and what you're actually trying to do instead of putting in lists and hoping people will think you're not using lists when you're using lists

Comment: thanks for the edit, but still it appears a list needs space 1. space text to be a list, not just 1. space text, but ok.

Comment: Nope, @user. But you should not "break out" of the list by NOT indenting the "Some text" above. When NOT indenting, the next list item is actually the first item of a NEW list, hence the number 1.

Comment: i thought to have a list i need to intend the numer... at least this is how it looks when you click the OL button on the wysywyg

Comment: You *could* [use `1)` and `2)`, or `1\.` and `2\.` to avoid creating a list](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35181/numbering-bullet-interpretation-bug/35206#35206), but why not format it as a proper list?