# Markdown ignores newline (after CSV)

Tags: support, markdown

I have been trying to edit the blockquote formatting in the question, [GPS Receiver SKG13BL + Arduino - Having trouble receiving data](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/21094/gps-receiver-skg13bl-arduino-having-trouble-receiving-data) on SE Arduino.

The issue I am having is with this piece of markup:

> [image: Troublesome markup]

which ends up looking like this:

> [image: Troublesome markup outout]

The final line in bold is appended to the previous line, and the newline is ignored.

*It is not actually the blockquoting causing the issue*. Working on that snippet in isolation, if the blockquotes are removed, the issue still occurs:

> [image: Without the blockquotes]

I have been playing with this for about an hour now, and can't find a solution.  I have tried copying and two pasting the previous line and writing in the `Position`... part, within it, manually, but as soon as I type the first space after the colon, the line appends itself to the previous one, like so:

**OK**

> [image: No space]

**Not OK**

> [image: With space]

I have added blank lines at the end of the blockquote, still nothing. IS it something to do with the CSV output upsetting the following line?

I have given up trying now, and need a pointer as to what I am missing, or doing wrong.

---

Here is the actual markup, if anyone wants to try themselves:

Here is the output:

$GPGSA,A,3,14,20,21,18,29,15,10,,,,,,2.59,1.13,2.33*0E $GPGSV,4,1,13,29,63,172,35,40,59,241,34,15,45,039,43,18,44,324,51*7A $GPGSV,4,2,13,21,42,350,46,10,27,284,46,24,27,116,19,14,25,209,17*76 $GPGSV,4,3,13,20,24,037,46,193,23,064,39,25,10,180,16,26,08,268,*44 $GPGSV,4,4,13,16,01,294,*42 $GPRMC,003218.000,A,1301.6703,N,07740.9225,E,0.02,0.00,010316,,,D*6D
Position: GPRMC,003218.000,A,1301.6703,N,07740.9225,E,0.02,0.00,010316,,,D*6D
**Position: lat: 1******8 lon: 7*****42**

Comment: OK, looking at [What is the reason for the top secret two space newline markdown weirdness?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40976/what-is-the-reason-for-the-top-secret-two-space-newline-markdown-weirdness), double space fixed the issue. Should I delete my question? I guess the answer is a resouding "yes"! :-)

Comment: If this is output, put it in code formatting (indent by four spaces).

Comment: @muru - ok, thanks. I have often wondered about that, and there seems to be a little inconsistency about this, across the SE sites - sometimes output is block quoted and other times it is code formatted - to which I have unfortunately probably contributed its perpetuation. Is this set in stone somewhere, or just an unspoken convention? Do you have a link?

Comment: I think it is an unspoken convention, if a logical one - if you want something to displayed exactly as given, code formatting is the way to go. IMO that applies to both sample input and sample output for a given program.

Comment: Don't delete it, having many ways of formulating a problem helps in future searches.

Comment: @DeerHunter - ok, I should answer my own question, then, and accept it?