# How to properly enter a newline in post text boxes

Tags: support, markdown

Should textarea boxes, like the one just I entered this text in to post, have a method to add a newline?

For instance, if I press enter once, the text does in fact have a newline in the text box that I entered it in, but in the preview nothing has changed.

If I press enter twice, it creates a newline but also a space in the middle.

So, could we just have a method to insert a normal newline?

Comment: @jonsca as we already have such method it's not a feature request but rather support issue.

Comment: The "space in the middle" is there for a reason; you hardly ever need just a line break. Please see the difference between [line breaks and paragraph breaks](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45617/why-you-should-press-return-key-2-times-to-insert-a-new-line/45635#45635) if you don't know.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Thanks.  I was more trying to stay with the spirit and intention of the original post, but I certainly see your point.  I was editing mainly for correctness of content, not to bring the request to the forefront, but you know the ol' bumping mechanism.

Comment: @jonsca yeah, as this has low view count took me some time to notice it's old post..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, to insert a single new line, type two spaces after the last character of the line.

For example, this:

This is my first line.
This is my second line.

There are two spaces after the period in the first line. (They are removed, however, when displayed).