# How to not get a blank line under a bold text?

Tags: support, markdown, code-formatting

If I hit enter or shift-enter after a bolded text and there's some text after that, I get a blank line. I don't want the blank line. I want the text to start at a new line without the extra new line.

Image where extra spaces don't do anything:
[image]

Comment: Can you post an example? I'm not quite sure what you mean.

Comment: [Paragraphs matter](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45617/why-you-should-press-return-key-2-times-to-insert-a-new-line/45635#45635), and I feel we should let the site owners decide how they are rendered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean like this?

**Bold Text**
Normal Text

Add two spaces after the end of the bold syntax (`**`), then a line break:

```
             vvV - Spaces under 'v's and a line break (enter or shift-enter) under 'V'
**Bold Text**  
Normal Text
```

This behavior is described by the [Markdown help for linebreaks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#linebreaks).

Comment: That's a neat trick, but the OP seems to be asking about removing blank lines, not adding new ones.

Comment: It's not working for me. I added tens of spaces. They translated into a single space in the preview.

Comment: @Robert Brandon has the right effect. There's no blank line but it's not working for me. The extra spaces are not breaking the line.

Comment: @Tony, can you post what you're doing in your question that way we can see it for ourselves? Doesn't matter if it works or not, just so we can see what you're writing.

Comment: I posted an image

Comment: @Tony, you forgot the actual line break. Two spaces, then a line break.