# literal carriage return character

Tags: discussion, feature-request, markdown

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why should users have to press Return twice to insert new lines?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45617/why-should-users-have-to-press-return-twice-to-insert-new-lines)

Apologies if this has been asked before (I can't find it, but that does not mean anything).

I have been editing things in /review, and a common issue is that users (especially new ones) seem to think that when they hit enter, and the cursor moves down a row, that that spacing will still exist in the final post. Why they don't look at the preview is beyond me, but that is besides the point.

Why does markdown not treat a carriage return as newline, and instead requires two spaces in front, and then a newline?

Would it not be easier/simpler to just make a carriage return all that is needed to get a newline?

Comment: +1 for "*Why they don't look at the preview is beyond me, but that is besides the point.*"