# No suitable answers affecting my acceptance rate

Tags: discussion

I have some questions which has answers but they are not relevant enough or some are off topic or some are not convincing.Hence I don't want to accept any answers.
But this is affecting my acceptance rate.
And I see people urging too increase your acceptance rate.
How to manage this?

Comment: Did you solve these problems by yourself in the meantime? If so, you can provide and accept your own answer. But as said, `86%` is good enough.

Comment: Or improve the question based on feedback given by comments/answers. This will increase the chance in getting the right answer.

Comment: @Felix I do. About 86% adding another question will get it down to 70's

Comment: (As an aside: in Markdown you need empty lines to get paragraphs. So, press Return twice to get a new paragraph, rather than [the line breaks you're using now](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45617/why-should-users-have-to-press-return-twice-to-insert-new-lines/45635#45635).)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your Accept Rate is 86% -- well above average.  Stop worrying!

Comment: What do I do if it gets on the wrong side?

Comment: @Shirish11 I have a 67% accept rate on StackOverflow and I never noticed it hurting my questions.  If it becomes a big issue: (1) answer your own questions, or improve an existing answer to make it acceptable. (2) Ask a good question you know the answer to and post the answer; if no one posts a *better* answer accept your own in a couple of days.

Answer (score 4):

You are not obliged in any way to accept answers. The **only** time you should accept an answer is if you felt it was the most helpful/correct.

If people harass you to improve your accept rate, ignore them - they're here for all the wrong reasons and frankly drag the whole community down.

For some time now, comments that complain about accept rate have been automatically deleted by the system when flagged, and I always flag them as too chatty/noise when I see them.

After all, if somebody is so worried about their rep, they should remember that it only takes two answer upvotes to gain more rep than having an answer accepted. Perhaps if they spent more time writing good answers, they wouldn't need them to be accepted.