# Add "paragraphs" to Markdown help

Tags: feature-request, markdown, editing-help, linebreak

Like balpha once [explained very nicely](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45617/why-should-users-have-to-press-return-twice-to-insert-new-lines/45635#45635), a `<br>` line break (newline) should be used
in very few cases, and surely is not the same as a new `<p>` paragraph. Still [the Markdown help](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help) only explains line breaks, not paragraphs:

[image: Help for line breaks: End a line with two spaces to add a BR linebreak]

Some sites [have](https://superuser.com/help/formatting) an additional *"New paragraphs only occur when there is a blank line. A single carriage does not create a new paragraph."*, but I feel that's not very clear*, and the emphasis is still on line breaks while it should be on paragraphs:

[image: Formatting help on Super User: additional help text]

So:

As a minimum, please add (rephrase) a note about the blank line, and maybe use *"Only when really needed [...] force"*:

> ### Paragraphs and line breaks
>
> Simply use a blank line between two paragraphs to start a new `<p>` paragraph. Only when really needed, end a line with two spaces to force a `<br/>` line break:
>
> ```
> How do I love thee?__    
> Let me count the ways
> ```

I'd even prefer an explicit example, simply as I think `<p>` should be favoured over `<br>` in most situations:

> ### Paragraphs and line breaks
>
> Simply use a blank line to start a new `<p>` paragraph:
>
> ```
> First sentence in the first paragraph. Another sentence. And a third. Maybe
> making this multiple consecutive lines of text, but still one paragraph.
>
> The second paragraph.
> ```
>
> Only when really needed, end a line with two spaces to force a `<br/>` line break:
>
> ```
> How do I love thee?__    
> Let me count the ways
> ```

Alternatively, slightly change the existing "Linebreaks"<sup>†</sup> part, and *above* that add a standalone section, [something like](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#p):

> ### Paragraphs
>
> A paragraph is simply one or more consecutive lines of text, separated by one or more blank lines:
>
> ```
> A blank line is any line that looks like a blank line. A line containing
> nothing but spaces or tabs is considered blank.
>
> Normal paragraphs should not be indented with spaces or tabs.
> ```
>
> ### Line breaks
>
> Only when really needed, end a line with two spaces to force a `<br/>` line break:
>
> ```
> How do I love thee?__    
> Let me count the ways
> ```

And: maybe even add a section "Paragraphs" to the inline post help on top of the editor? I'm not sure which help tab should then be shown [when auto-expanding it for new users](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/04/inline-comment-and-post-markdown-help/) though.

---

<sup>*</sup> Also note how not all sites highlight the two spaces with a different background color.

<sup>†</sup> Yes, I think "line break" likes a space too...