# Is there a better way than <br> to force a newline?

Tags: support, edits, markdown, design

When I want to start a new line, I've always used `<br>`. I'm wondering if there's a better way, however, that only uses Markdown. I'm aware that if you insert two line breaks, leaving a blank line, it works, like this:

But what if I don't want a blank line like you see above this line? I don't have a problem with using `<br>`, but it just seems like such a common task shouldn't require four extra characters when Markdown is supported.

Comment: Double space is for you. And you probably need to look at [Markdown help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: You shouldn't ever *need* to start a new line, really. Splitting paragraphs with line breaks makes sense for prose, IMO, but on Stack Exchange? I don't know.

Comment: You shouldn't force newlines, except possibly when you're writing a poem. In all other cases, you should force a new *paragraph*.

Comment: I agree with balpha and slhck why force a line break.

Comment: Yes. It's called `<br/>`.

Comment: In case you think you need line breaks, then please read about [the difference between a line break and a paragraph](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45617/why-should-users-have-to-press-return-twice-to-insert-new-lines/45635#45635).

Comment: @slhck I use new lines in a good 50% of my answers in the form **bold paragraph title** [new line] paragraph. For example here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17907255/make-the-computer-never-lose-at-tic-tac-toe/17907534#17907534

Comment: @RichardTingle That is very unusual formatting and not according to any style guide, or proper HTML semantics either. What you're doing is  putting a pseudo-heading into a paragraph, while instead you should use an HTML heading element like `<h1>` through `<h3>`.

Comment: @slhck aren't html elements workarounds, for use only where markdown is unavailable (eg ** are preferable to <b></b> except as a workaround for intraword emphasis).

Comment: @RichardTingle You can use `#` through `###` to create the headings. I edited your post to give you an example.

Comment: @slhck thats actually very nice. I'll look into using that

Comment: Also, @Richard, using headings (or at least paragraphs) is so much nicer for people using screen readers. Now the screen reader understands it's a heading, not just some random bold text in a sentence. (Lacking the dot, "Conceptual implementation So you create a branching structure" was really just one sentence, regardless of the explicit line break.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can add two trailing spaces to the end of the line:

This is a sentence
followed by a newline

Where:

```
This is a sentence    
------------------^^
```

Comment: Where is this stuff documented?

Comment: Documented, [in the Markdown help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#linebreaks), @Cole, but [not recommended](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45617/why-should-users-have-to-press-return-twice-to-insert-new-lines/45635#45635). Strangely enough, the blank line for a paragraph [is not in that official documentation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135252/add-paragraphs-to-markdown-help).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can, end your line with two spaces:

> This is my line
>   broken without <br>

This is my line
Broken without <br>

Comment: Thank you too. I would accept this, but I wasn't sure which one was posted first (they both said 18 minutes ago) and (no offense) Jon Clements' post was more clear.

Comment: @flarn2006 if you mouse over the timestamp text, you get more detailed time information. Also if you mouse over the `share` links, you can see the post id (the first number) - these are issued in strict chronological order. So you can see that this post was made ten seconds before the other. But I wouldn't worry about it :)