# How to do a single newline

Tags: discussion, markdown, newline

How do I do a single newline/carriage return when typing a question or answer?

For example, if I wanted to write some columns with values as in an [Excel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Excel) spreadsheet. I see people do it all the time, but I don't know how. I read the formatting tips and all about the blockquote stuff... did some google'ing, but I still haven't found out how.

The only way I know to do newlines is by pressing the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key twice, which makes a new *paragraph*, creating an empty line, which is not what I want.

Comment: Did you already try <br/> like in HTML?

Comment: Thanks Tim. <br/> works ! I didn't think of that one. I can use shift+enter here for newlines, but when asking a question or answering one I have to use <br/> tags. Okay. got it.
edit:
You can put that solution in as an answer so it can be voted on.
Respectfully,
Josh

Comment: I find that sometimes <br> is needed too, depending on the situation

Comment: So it looks like that meta part of the site deals with questions pertaining to mechanics of the stackoverflow site itself. Please correct me if it is anything different or anything more.

Comment: Beware of the small screens, where such tables do not have scrollbars [but are wrapped](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73566/is-there-any-markdown-to-create-tables/73567#73567).

Comment: Related: balpha wrote [a long answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/45635/131713) to a related question explaining why the two-line rule exists.

Comment: hit `Spacebar` twice.  then `Enter`

Comment: As u useful comment was wiped when other answers to this question were deleted, let me repeat one very good reason not to use `<br`>: *`<br/>` creates formatting messes later for someone trying to go back and edit to clean up other things (say, by applying a `<pre>` tag -- suddenly all that markup is visible), and it's the harder way to do this anyway. – Joel Coehoorn♦ Jul 5 '12 at 16:05*

Answer (score 81, accepted):

You can type two spaces    and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
Like so.

> I wanted to write some columns with values as in an Excel spreadsheet

For longer/pasted text, you can also [format as code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) in many ways, like by indenting with 4 spaces, or by using `<pre></pre>` tags (which need manual encoding of HTML), like so:

```
Column 1   Column 2   Column 3
value 1      13            26
value 2      11            22
```

Comment: But as an aside: line breaks should [not be confused with (or abused for) paragraphs](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45617/why-should-users-have-to-press-return-twice-to-insert-new-lines/45635#45635).

Comment: @gobernador, Why not use `<br>` instead?

Comment: Is that useful?
        of no use

Comment: @kdh, I mean typing `<br>` instead of typing "space" + "space" + "newline". Try it, it works.

Comment: @Pacerier as Pops said in a  comment to a now deleted answer, "Markdown should be preferred over HTML" - which makes sense. Raw HTML should be used with care and only when there's no Markdown alternative.

Comment: @ShadowWizard, That's true only if a future CSS template might display them differently. However, `<br>` and "space" + "space" + "newline" are synonymous  regardless of styling.

Comment: testing the new line now <br> my new line

Comment: test<br>
it works really ?

Comment: @jitenshah: HTML tags don't work in comments, only in posts. There's no way that I know of to insert line breaks in comments (except for MathJax hacks on sites that have it enabled).

Answer (score 7):

Use the HTML line break tag '`<br>`'. See the example below where Line 1 uses the line break and line 2 uses the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

**Example** (1: `<br>`, 2: <kbd>Enter</kbd>)

Line 1 
Line 2
Line 3

Click the *Edit* button on this post here for good reference.

Comment: That works, but there are already three deleted answers suggesting that, all with negative scores. People don't like HTML when there's a Markdown solution :)

Comment: The two spaces + enter is a lot more elegant, especially in markdown view. I'm sure there's times (and spaces) for html, but doublespacing what I recommend.

Comment: For me, this answer is useful.