# How to make two newlines?

Tags: support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to do newlines on the stackoverflow website?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138776/how-to-do-newlines-on-the-stackoverflow-website)

Say I want to make two newlines between my paragraphs - is that possible to do without using `<br/>`, which [as I've read here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138776/how-to-do-newlines-on-the-stackoverflow-website) is not encouraged?

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: There is more than one answer in the question you linked to, making this post an exact duplicate of the other.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not encouraged because it creates excess vertical white-space, which spreads out the post across the screen and allows less content to appear on the page overall. There's really no reason where you'd need to do this, and I guarantee you someone would edit the extra line-break out. Just start a new paragraph if you need some spacing between two lines of text.

In the specific case you linked too, however, the newline is discouraged because it's not the proper way to format that kind of data (columns from an Excel spreadsheet) in a post.

Comment: Very true, and also: let the site that renders it decide how things look. If one day the Stack Exchange site decide to put more whitespace between paragraphs, then suddenly all the hacks might look very bad. Maybe today already people are using [the public data dumps](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/stack-overflow-creative-commons-data-dump/) with some totally different look and feel. And on mobile screen estate is even more limited, why force people to scroll even more?