# Why no CRs in questions?

Tags: support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to do newlines on the Stack Overflow website?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138776)

When I ask a question, I try to use carriage returns to aid clarity.

They are stripped when they appear in the forum.

Is there a way to use the CRs?

Answer (score 4):

Stack Overflow uses [Markdown](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown). To add a newline to a question or answer, leave two spaces at the end of the previous line. To start a new paragraph, press <kbd>Enter</kbd> twice between lines.

Comment: Or add "<br/>" at the end of a line.

Comment: However, note that an explicit newline is hardly ever needed, and one should most likely [use paragraphs instead](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45617/why-should-users-have-to-press-return-twice-to-insert-new-lines/45635#45635) (using the empty line like Dave described above). And remember that the content is not only shown in desktop browsers, and any explicit formatting (including explicit newlines) might actually look bad on other platforms, or might make screen readers read the text as one loooong paragraph.

Comment: As for `<br>`, see the comments [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138776/how-to-do-newlines-on-the-stackoverflow-website/138777#138777), @Peter.