# Accept rate stat not visible

Tags: support, accept-rate

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Let’s stop displaying a user’s accept rate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136951/lets-stop-displaying-a-users-accept-rate)

Am I missing something in my configuration or browser setup?

The Accept Rate stat is no longer visible for every user I have checked. Has something changed about this stat?

Comment: As an aside: please note @Ben's nice edit. (Please [read about the difference between a line break and a paragraph break](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45617/why-should-users-have-to-press-return-twice-to-insert-new-lines/45635#45635). Thanks!)

Comment: Ha, I had expected this question a lot sooner.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Has something changed about this stat?

Yes. [It is no longer displayed on questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/164654/140505). The stat was not useful or constructive and is no longer with us.

RIP, Accept Rate.

Comment: Thanks, now I think I am a bit stupid, should have searched better.

Comment: @Steve, there's always [Recent feature changes to Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange) as linked from the Meta home page.

Comment: @Arjan added to my bookmarks, thanks to you also