# Can Stack Overflow give a chance to renew a downvoted question?

Tags: feature-request, questions, down-votes, notifications

As everyone knows, many questions are being voted down because of unclear, too broad, opinion-based, off-topic reasons and so on. Then the voted down questions would be deleted or closed, which make the owners to publish a new improved one.

Voting down a question is a way to prompt the question's owner to improve their question. So, it would be better to verify whether the owner of a question pays effort to improve the question if he has a chance to renew their question.

'Renew' means prepend a renew tag to the question title or clear the downvoted score and promote this question to the front like a new one. When one renews a question, the site can send a notification to each one who voted down to review the question. I think it will be more efficient to solve problems and improve the quality of questions.

Comment: Questions that are edited are brought up to the front of the page (for a short while), and they are voted down because they do not show any research effort, are not clear, or are not useful.  Adding a tag to suddenly "clear" the opinions of the community who felt that this question should be downvoted is...a bad idea.

Comment: Note that downvotes [feed the automatic posting bans](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56817/can-we-prevent-some-of-the-low-quality-questions-from-entering-our-system/60294#60294) -- which is there for very good reasons. Automatically removing downvotes after some edit would defeat that.

Comment: (Please take care of whitespace [after paragraphs](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45617/why-should-users-have-to-press-return-twice-to-insert-new-lines/45635#45635), dots and commas. Thanks.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With the [recent changes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173497/every-close-has-its-thorn-replace-close-with-on-hold-for-the-first-five-d), questions that are not a good fit for the site (as mentioned in the [Help Center](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)) are marked as *on hold* for 5 days instead of being marked as *closed*. A question which is on hold (or closed) can be edited and improved by the original poster. This editing will automatically move that question to the re-open queue where users can vote to reopen it thus the question will reappear on the front page again (top in the list of questions in the 'active' tab).

Hence I don't see a need for a *renew* tag as you have suggested.

Comment: Closed questions can still be edited, improved, and reopened, just like on hold questions.  This has always been the case.  "on hold" is literally nothing more than a name change so that new users realize that they can do those things, rather than assuming that they can't based on the name.

Comment: @Servy correct me if I am wrong here, but editing a 'on hold' questions automatically puts it in the reopen review queue as opposed to the closed questions.

Comment: @Servy - I think the name change worked.

Comment: @AzizShaikh All closed questions were put in the reopen queue until the recent change.  I have seen no announcement stating that this behavior has changed, so it is my understanding that you are in fact incorrect; and that closed questions will go in the reopen queue when edited.  If that is no longer the case, it should not have been changed, but I doubt highly doubt that change has happened.

Comment: @AzizShaikh You are indeed wrong, the change to “on hold” is purely a change in name, not in behavior. It came along with changes in close reasons. But it was already the case before that questions edited by the asker after they had been closed were placed in the reopen queue.

Answer (score 5):

Can I address some of the inaccuracies in your "Everyone knows" sentence? Because what you think everyone knows is not in fact correct.

> many questions are being voted down because of unclear, too broad, opinion-based, off-topic reasons and so on. Then the voted down questions would be deleted or closed, which make the owners to publish a new improved one.

Questions are voted down because they are poorly written, don't contain enough detail, don't show that the person tried to solve the problem themselves, or just because the voter is having a grumpy day. Your list of "unclear, too broad, opinion-based, off-topic..." is actually why questions gather close votes, not downvotes. (I know some people deliver both at once, I do not.)

Being closed should **never** make the owner publish a new improved one. That will lead you to a question ban. Being closed (or on hold as we now say) should make the owner improve the question they wrote. That is what it is for.

Editing an on hold question will put it in a re-open queue. Editing a question whether open or closed will put in on the front page. This might result in someone removing their downvote or someone upvoting you. More importantly, it might get you an answer.

On that matter of indicating (especially to downvoters) that a question has been improved, there is [a feature request for that](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1751/allow-an-edit-to-notify-downvoters-i-think-ive-fixed-the-issue-now-please-c) but aparently it's not going to happen. That's too bad.  However being able to clear all your downvotes just by clicking a button - nobody wants that to happen. Downvotes hurt - if you could just wash them away, you surely would. But the site thrives because you can't.