# Tests in review shows check mark

Tags: bug, review-audits

I just had a test in the First Posts reviews.
I needed to review a answer, and it was marked a right.
This big green check-mark is clearly visible, and makes the test useless.

Comment: in rare occasions, accepted answer can be epicly bad. I remember a discussion about a question where the OP posted his own answer saying something like "nevermind, we decided not to do this" and mark it as "accepted".

Comment: @ColeJohnson, I concur

Comment: @OldCheck Oh, so you're doubleDown! I always thought you were a relatively new user and I was wondering how you were doing so well on meta :P

Comment: (As an aside, please note that line breaks (which you are using) [are not paragraphs](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45617/why-should-users-have-to-press-return-twice-to-insert-new-lines/45635#45635). Please use paragraphs for English text. Thanks!)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean. Just because an answer is accepted, doesn't:

- mean it's a good answer (e.g. it could be link-only, or some such)
- mean it can't be improved
- mean the answer is a legitimate one
- (but, most importantly) **mean you have no suggestions for the OP**

Accepted answers don't mean much beyond what the asker thought was a useful response. Answers can still be improved, and if they're first posts, it's very likely that this is the case.