# Help page not clear about 'auto award' on your own bounty

Tags: feature-request, help-center, wording

On the [Help/Bounty Page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) under heading "How is a bounty awarded?", in the first paragraph about manually awarding a bounty it states:

> (You cannot award a bounty to your own answer.)

Which is quite clear.

The following paragraph describes how the auto award works, however it doesn't state you cannot be auto awarded your own bounty (or anywhere in the help/bounty page).

It's a bit misleading, as the paragraph above it quite clearly states I cannot award a bounty to my own answer.
It would be pointless to be able to auto earn your own bounty and lose half the rep, but perhaps someone can make it concise by adding to the "auto award" paragraph "(You cannot be auto awarded a bounty you placed.)"

Or better yet just under the heading **How is a bounty awarded?** you could put "You cannot in any way obtain a bounty (in full or part) that you have placed (including awarding to yourself or auto awarded)".

There may be other pages where this is not clear, this is one:
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties

It's no biggy, just an FYI for possible improvement.

Comment: (As an aside: [another FYI for possible improvement](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45617/why-should-users-have-to-press-return-twice-to-insert-new-lines/45635#45635). `;-)`)

Comment: If `"You cannot be auto awarded a bounty you placed"`, it should also be clarified what happens if your answer is the highest voted answer subject to the specified criteria. Does it just go to the next highest scoring answer, does it get refunded, or what?

Comment: @Dukeling in what scenario? If you cannot manually or be auto awarded a bounty you placed, surely this covers all bases? Else if you didn't place the bounty and yours is highest voted answer you get the auto award (after manual award and after an accepted answer, if bounty placed by questioner)

Comment: @James Just as I said. If your answer was the highest-scoring, was posted after the bounty was raised and has a score of 2 or more (which are the criteria for getting the bounty), and was thus supposed to get the bounty, the logical thing to do would be to have the next highest-scoring, eligible answer get it, and if there is no such answer, it gets refunded. But maybe it just gets refunded, I don't know. Thus clarification required.

Comment: @Dukeling: the help pages relating to bounty are pretty clear on "no refund ever", coupled with "You may not cancel a bounty once it has been started".

Comment: @James Ok, maybe not refunded, but then "not awarded to anyone" (my limited exposure to bounties are through Meta questions, which did actually involve cases of refunds, though possibly by moderators, I can't remember the exact details).

Comment: Have a read: http://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty "If there's no answer meeting those criteria, the bounty is not awarded to anyone."

Comment: @James That's exactly were I copied "not awarded to anyone" from.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Dam I spent ages deciding those tags, didn't think this was a "feature" to be honest. Thanks :)

Comment: @James yep, you're asking to change text/wording in the help center.