# Why do I need 2 carriage returns for a visible carriage return?

Tags: discussion

Whenever I post anything (answer/question) I have to hit [RETURN] twice to make one visible return. I don't like reading one long-go text. I like it in paragraphs.

This is a text with one carriage return for each new line:

> Hello. 
>   This is an example text. 
>   I like reading in paragraphs. 
>   Not in one-long go.

And here a text with each line separated by 2 returns:

> Hello.
>
> This is an example text.
>
> I like reading in paragraphs.
>
> Not in one-long go.
>
> And it's easier to navigate!

Why this behaviour? how do I modify it?

Comment: Use 2 Enter for paragraph. If you want line break, use 2 spaces at the end of the line.

Comment: ah soo. thanks. didn't know :P but still requires me to press multiple keys heh.

Comment: See this question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26011/should-the-markdown-renderer-treat-a-single-line-break-as-br

Answer (score -1):

Either add 2 spaces at the end of the line

```
test<space><space>  
test
```

or add a `<br>` at the end of the line

```
test<br>
test
```

Comment: No. [Line breaks are not paragraphs](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45617/why-should-users-have-to-press-return-twice-to-insert-new-lines/45635#45635).

Comment: mhm if there is no other way we will have to go with this ; >

Comment: No, @Gam, not for English text. Please read the link above. (And then try to read [the same, with line breaks](http://i.stack.imgur.com/svdTY.png).)