# Line breaks don't count in the edited character count

Tags: bug, edits, suggested-edits

I came across a question today on the parenting site and the post was decent and communicated the problem well, except the formatting was horrible.  The post used proper sentences and everything, but had no line breaks at all, leading to one huge wall-of-text paragraph.

Since I don't have enough rep there to edit outright I tried to suggest an edit where all I did was to put in the line breaks to create readable paragraphs.  Upon trying to save, the system gave me an error that edits must be a minimum of 6 characters.  I couldn't find anything else that needed correcting, but could not submit the edit due to the character restriction.

(Note: I made 5-6 paragraphs out of the one mega-paragraph, so there were about 10-12 line breaks added to the post.)

Is this a bug or intended behavior?  If it is intended, how would I make such an edit in the future?

Comment: Closely related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87200/pure-code-formatting-to-enhance-a-question-is-impossible-without-2k-rep

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do I need 2 carriage returns for a visible carriage return?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/171173/282094) and answer: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/45635/282094